# Como obter a resposta do servidor de forma eficiente?

Tags: c#, winforms

Eu estou a criar uma aplicação Cliente/Servidor
Funciona como um chat então o servidor pode enviar mensagens para o cliente e vise-versa.

Para enviar mensagens eu uso um evento

```
private void btnsend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            enviar();
 }
```

Significa que quando clico no botão ele executa essa function que envia a mensagem ao servidor.

Para receber as mensagens do servidor eu pensei em usar timer ou also parecido;
tentei primeiro com um while deste modo;

```
private void btnsend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
                enviar();
                While(true)
               {
                 Receber();
               }

     }
```

Mas logo percebi que ficaria infinito e não conseguiria mais usar o enviar então pensei no timer.

Outra tentativa foi fazer o seguinte

```
private void btnsend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            enviar();
        }


        public  void enviar()
        {

            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(ntcpClient.GetStream());
            writer.AutoFlush = true;
            writer.WriteLine(gettime() + ":" + txtmsgsend.Text );
            this.txtmsg.Text += gettime() +":" + txtmsgsend.Text + "\n";
            txtmsgsend.Text = "";
            if (txtmsgsend.Text == "/clear")
            {
                txtmsg.Text = "";
            }
            receber();
        }
```

Mas tem um problema apenas verifico se recebi uma mensagem se enviar uma mensagem o que continua sem solucionar o problema.

[Codigo inteiro](https://pastebin.com/MTK18mp1)

Comment: A questão do `while(1)` é só você fazer de forma assincrona, dê uma olhada no namespace `System.Threading.Task`. Mas não faça isso dentro de um evento, crie um método void e chame-o no `Load()`.

Comment: Possível é, mas não é a solução, isto consumirá processamento ou terá que esperar pelo tempo certo, seria melhor criar uma arquitetura que fica esperando chegar uma mensagem.

Comment: Algum exemplo é que não entendi mesmo